# Insert/Update record using mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to insert a record into mongodb, using mongoose, but the record does not update when record is already in the database. Is there something I am doing wrong? The documentation for mongoose is not the easiest to follow for me.

```
models.fg_records.update({email:clean_email}, inactive_user, {update: true}, function (err) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transport.sendMail(message, function(err, response) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                view('<ul><li>There was a problem sending an email to this user. Make sure you types it correctly.</li></ul>');
            } else {
                res.redirect('/records');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try passing the option 'upsert' to the update function, instead of 'update', which is not a valid option [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-update).

```
models.fg_records.update({email:clean_email}, inactive_user, {upsert: true}, function (err) { ... }):
```